# How to save cameraRoll asset uri to cloudinary using React native?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, cloudinary

> Here i am using CameraRoll component to display the  local images
>   .This local images i need to save to the cloudinary through
>   node.js.But my CameraRoll asset uri  generating like below

```
var assetURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B37E1F30-C8F4-4648-8BF2-1B8BD638141D&ext=JPG”;
```

> But the images are not saved in cloudinary through node(it's expecting
>   base64 format)

Comment: I got the solution please follow this https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/accessing-iphone-camera-roll-images-react-native

Answer (score -1):

[here](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript), you can find some information on how to convert Image object to data URI.
See if it helps.

Comment: How can i do this with react native but  here document is not working in react native